# The titlesec package with explicit option meet error when \section contains a command

Tags: formatting, titlesec, section-titles

I use the titlesec with explicit option to modify the section's format.
The code compiles perfectly with texts. However, when I put a command in the section.
LaTeX meets error "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \section{Try \LaTeX}".
Please help fix the below codes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{15}{17}\bfseries\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
{\thesection.}{.5em}
{\fontsize{15}{17}\selectfont{#1}
\xdef\rightmark{Sec \arabic{section}.\, #1}}[]
\begin{document}
\section{Try \LaTeX}
\section{Try Try $ \mathbb{R} $}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try formatting the header with `titleps` instead (just add the `[pagestyles]` option)? You won't need the `explicit` option.

Comment: I do not know why, but adding \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} to the preamble eliminates your error, but you get the message that the font for your codes in the titles is not available. For $\S$ in the section title you do not get an error, so the cause may be the symbols in combination with the font you chose.

Comment: you shouldn't use \xdef on arbitrary latex code. That is bound to explode somewhere. And defining \rightmark like this is wrong anyway, it will give wrong headers.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your suggestion. 
My code has been corrected. 
Can you tell me why above code meet error?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your advice.
But this does not make the error.

Comment: @C.Peters I don't know too!

Comment: @NamTranLe: au contraire, I think Ulrike is absolutely right. Just try `\xdef\rightmark{\LaTeX}` and see things break. (If you commend out the `\xdef` line your code compiles fine for me.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. Thank you for your advice. I remove \xdef command and redefine \leftmark. It is ok.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never want to `\xdef\rightmark`.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{15}{17}\bfseries\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
  {\thesection.}
  {.5em}
  {\fontsize{15}{17}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{Sec \arabic{section}.\ #1}}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\section{Try \LaTeX}

Some text\clearpage

\section{Try Try $ \mathbb{R} $}

Some text\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

The picture has been produced with A6 paper to make a smaller one.

For changing the page style you can use `fancyhdr`:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{15}{17}\bfseries\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
  {\thesection.}
  {.5em}
  {\fontsize{15}{17}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{Section \arabic{section}.\ #1}}

\fancypagestyle{namtramle}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\pagestyle{namtramle}

\begin{document}

\section{Try \LaTeX}

Some text\clearpage

\section{Try Try $ \mathbb{R} $}

Some text\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! 
However, the header texts are not true!

Comment: @NamTranLe You can modify their appearance with `fancyhdr` or `titleps`. I wanted to show how to correctly set the `\rightmark`

Comment: Here is the compile result. The code was posted in my answer.
https://im.ge/i/TeqFF
P.S I don't know how to upload an image to this comment!

Comment: @NamTranLe Not with the code I showed. Now your task is to make a new question with the details.

Comment: Sorry. It is the original question. It is in the right mark, not uppercase.

Comment: @NamTranLe I added a possible solution

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The code can be corrected by **titleps** package. But I don't know why the first code meet error.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{15}{17}\bfseries\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
{\thesection.}{.5em}
{\fontsize{15}{17}\selectfont}[]
\usepackage{titleps}
  \newpagestyle{main}[\small]{
    \setheadrule{.55pt}%
    \sethead{Section \thesection.\; \sectiontitle}% odd-left
            {}%  odd-center
            {\thepage}% odd-right
  }
  \pagestyle{main}
\begin{document}
\section{Try \LaTeX}
\newpage
\section{Try $ \mathbb{R} $}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg This is my corrected code